# MySQL v5.7/5.6 Cannot add Foreign Key constraint

Tags: mysql

I tried putting this through db-fiddle and SQL fiddle Keep getting "Schema Error: Error: ER_CANNOT_ADD_FOREIGN: Cannot add foreign key constraint"
Everything works until I put the last table.

'''

```
    CREATE TABLE User (
    User_ID     INT      NOT NULL,
    First_Name  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Last_Name   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Address_1   VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    Address_2   VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    City        VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    State       VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    Zip         VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Mobile_Phone    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (User_ID)
    );

    CREATE TABLE Bagel (
    Bagel_ID        INT NOT NULL,
    Bagel_Name      VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Bagel_Description   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Bagel_Price     NUMERIC(65,2)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Bagel_ID)
    );

   CREATE TABLE Bagel_Order (
   Bagel_Order_ID   INT     NOT NULL,
   User_ID      INT     NOT NULL,
   Order_Date       TIMESTAMP,
   Delivery_Fee         NUMERIC(50 , 2) NOT NULL,
   Special_Notes        CHAR,
   PRIMARY KEY (Bagel_Order_ID),
   FOREIGN KEY (User_ID) REFERENCES User (User_ID)
   );

   CREATE TABLE Bagel_Order_Line_Item (
   Bagel_Order_ID   INT     NOT NULL,
   Bagel_ID         INT     NOT NULL,
   Bagel_Quantity       INT     NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(Bagel_Order_ID, Bagel_ID),  
   FOREIGN KEY(Bagel_Order_ID) REFERENCES 
   Bagel_Order_Line_Item(Bagel_Order_ID),
   FOREIGN KEY(Bagel_ID) REFERENCES Bagel(Bagel_ID)
   );
```

'''

Comment: your code does not produce the error see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ad9f0fae6d478d57681a09d6558dc067

Comment: Thats weird because when I put it through it give me this see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aQaGiFU5m16agoGoniwQcU/0

Comment: dbfiddle.uk is uptodate , your site has an older version, which leads to false conclusions use `SELECT version()` to determine if you have the same version like the dbfiddle sites

Comment: Change `... FOREIGN KEY(Bagel_Order_ID) REFERENCES Bagel_Order_Line_Item(Bagel_Order_ID) ...` by `... FOREIGN KEY(Bagel_Order_ID) REFERENCES Bagel_Order(Bagel_Order_ID) ...`, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aQaGiFU5m16agoGoniwQcU/2).